# push to array with JS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you tell me how to add the text from text field to the array so it is displayed at the top of text field?
Thanks

```
<div id="test">
    <p id="items"></p>
    <input type="text" id="color" />
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" />
</div>
<script>
    var theArray = new Array("Red", "Green", "Blue");
    var target = $("#items");
    for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
        target.append("<p>" + theArray[i] + "</p>");
    }
    $("#add").click(function () {});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    var color = $("#color").val()
    theArray.push(color);
    target.prepend("<p>" + color + "</p>");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/R5PNL/1/)

Comment: Since he want it on the top, use `.prepend()`.

Comment: Thanks i will probably post more silly questions like it soon.

Comment: @user2976554, If you are putting effort we are ready to help.